# Can I use the same built in flash library from Chrome in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash, google-chrome

Chrome comes with flash support by default, Firefox does not. If I use both on my system is there a way to use the library responsible displaying flash content in Chrome to do the same in Firefox?

Comment: For clarity, the Chromium browser does not ship with Flash and uses the same Flash plugin as Firefox.

Comment: It does? ^^ but Chrome does ship with it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Flash is only distributed with the i386 builds of Flash. The rest of the answer is based on that (I'm using 64bit)

On a 32bit computer, the Chrome version of flash will be at `/opt/google/chrome/libflashplayergc.so`. If you have this, you could try copying/symlinking this around, it should still be using NPAPI so should be compatible with Firefox.

If that file doesn't exist, you're probably like me and don't have it.

---

I have Chrome installed and it claims (in `about:plugins`, click the "details" link) that it's using `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` plugin. This is the same one that Firefox is using.

You can also run `locate libflash` to have a quick look over the system for versions of Flash. `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` is the only version I have on the computer (the others are symlinks).

You should note that later this year (assuming their plans turn out) Chrome/Chromium will switch to a PPAPI version of Flash (from the NPAPI one it shares with Firefox). So whatever instructions you do get, they'll stop working at some point this year... Unless Mozilla backtracks and decides to support PPAPI (which is also possible).

I have had a look at the `google-chrome-stable`, `-beta` and `-unstable` packages and none of them have a Flash plugin in them.

Comment: So, if you have the `flashplugin-installer` package in your chrome will use by default the plugin from the Adobe installation? What if you did not install the flash plugin from Adobe?

Comment: Honestly no idea. As I've just expanded, I don't have the "official for-Chrome" plugin because I'm on 64bit and the plugin only ships with the 32bit packages. I would assume that Chrome would pick its own version of the plugin though.

Comment: Thx man, explains why I cant follow the instructions I read some where (Im also using 64bits).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same flash library for both browsers.

Flash is directly integrated into Chrome and all updates are automatic for it. If you wish to use flash on other browsers you need to install it separately from Adobe for Firefox.

[Reference](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086)

Comment: I dont like the answer from Google over this ;) I know you could with with some easy steps do it. I am testing this at the moment.