# Use The Google Chrome 21 Flash Plugin in Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, google-chrome

I see several link for doing this :

- [Can I use the same built in flash library from Chrome in Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108479/can-i-use-the-same-built-in-flash-library-from-chrome-in-firefox)
- http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/use-the-google-chrome-flash-plugin-in-firefox-in-ubuntu/

But there is not any libgcflashplugin.so or libflashplayergc.so in /opt/google/chrome directory (in Google Chrome 21).
I find /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so and create a link to /.mozilla/plugins/ but firefox did not know it as a plugin.

How can i use The Google Chrome 21 Flash Plugin in Firefox (14) in Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks.

Comment: I also had tried this way and didn't work. Anyway, it's directory where Google locating Flash Player in its Chromium Engine.

Maybe It's end for Firefox in Linux. I mean end of supporting Flash

Comment: You can use "Adobe Flash Plugin" instead of Google Chrome Flash Plugin, but i hope we can find a solution for using Google Chrome Flash Plugin in Firefox because it is more reliable than"Adobe Flash Plugin".

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109213/flash-videoplayer-not-working-properly

Comment: There is not anyway to do this?

Comment: No need for flash in the future. HTML5 ;)

Comment: @blade19899 In the future not now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i find answer to my question:

Google Chrome 21 use [Pepper project](http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/) for supporting flash and mozilla team said in his [wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aPepper):

> Mozilla is not interested in or working on Pepper at this time. See the Chrome [Pepper pages](http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/).

Therefore it seems there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [FreshPlayerPlugin](https://github.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin) that implements a wrapper between NPAPI and Pepper API. it should be able to make the Chrome flash player plugin adapt in Firefox.